# Removing Unicode/invalid characters from string

Tags: java, regex, unicode, coldfusion

I've had this problem before, and finally wrote some code to fix it (I remember it was an easy fix). But, I had to revert to a version of code from a few weeks back, and lost what I wrote.

I'm dealing with ID3 tags using 'org.farng.mp3' and I run into invalid characters like the 'Replacement Character', char 65533, \u25AF, etc. in some tags.

Input: **Electronic**
Which output like this:**E�l�e�c�t�r�o�n�i�c**

I know they are UTF-8 encoded, so I'm not sure if I need to try to encode them into some other char set.

Here are some of the replacements I've used (and variations of the below):

```
<cfset tag = REReplace(tag,"\\p{C}", "", "All")>
<cfset tag = REReplace(tag,"\p{Cf}", "", "All")>
<cfset tag = ReReplace(tag,"[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "", "All")>    
<cfset tag = Replace(tag, "[\\u25AF]", "", "All")>
<cfset tag = ReplaceNoCase(tag,chr(65533),"","All")>
```

I've looked through all old resolutions I've found previously, and nothing is working, but I know it's something I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE/Resolved**

Here is what worked for me:

```
<cfset tag = REReplace(tag,"[^\w ]","","All")>
```

Comment: Check cflib.org to see if there is an existing UDF that meets your needs.

Comment: The occurrence between each character makes me wonder if you're source isn't actually UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: My apologies. It is UTF-16. The other album I was testing was UTF-8 ---- ID3v2.30 82242
compression        = false
unsynchronization  = false
crcData            = 0
crcDataFlag        = false
experimental       = false
extended           = false
paddingSize        = 0
TRCK
Text Encoding = UTF-16
Text = ÿþ1/6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. After looking all over, I finally found the solution, and it was simple like I thought. Update in the post.

Comment: @upgrad3 Please remove the update to your question that provides your solution. The appropriate way to post a resolution is to post an answer, and you have already done that. As a separate matter, could you also accept your answer, because questions with an accepted answer are more helpful for the community.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple Regex that worked for me:

```
<cfset tag = REReplace(tag,"[^\w ]","","All")>
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex "word" filter may work, but some non-decorative, international UTF-8 characters could be dropped.

I've used a lot of different methods. If you want to convert Unicode to ASCII7 using ColdFusion, I highly recommend checking out [Junidecode](https://github.com/gcardone/junidecode). (I shared some proof-of-concept code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56600717/693068).)

There are couple different methods other than the third-party JAR library, but your mileage will vary. I highly recommend performing a unit test with a large sample to ensure that it is doing what you expect.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/ae63641dc0fdd5138cc8b2f5ee92f032) that you can test at [TryCF.com](https://www.trycf.com/).

### rereplace (strip all high ASCII characters)

```java
k = "E�l�e�c�t�r�o�n�i�c";
k2 = rereplace(k, "[^\x20-\x7E]", "", "ALL");
// k2 is now "Electronic"
```

### Java (convert if possible. if not, strip)

Use `java.text.Normalizer`, but be aware that it may strip anything it doesn't understand. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642205/693068))

```java
k = "E�l�e�c�t�r�o�n�i�c";
k2 = createObject( 'java', 'java.text.Normalizer' ).normalize( k, createObject( 'java', 'java.text.Normalizer$Form' ).valueOf('NFD') ).replaceAll('\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+','').replaceAll('[^\p{ASCII}]+','');
// k2 is now "Electronic"
```